# Handling mouseover events when JavaScript is off

Tags: javascript, dom-events

We have several menus that use a mouse-over event and JavaScript to show the underlying list.  How would you handle something like this if JavaScript is off?

Are there any special keyboard short cuts?

Is there a fallback that would work?

Were trying to see how accessible our site is in certain configurations and no JavaScript is one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well no.

The whole thing of mouseover is a js implementation if there is no js, you have **no** mouseover effects..

So when you know a user has js turned off: change how your site acts in response to certain actions a user might do.

Comment: Yep, a repeater is created which creates the hidden list.

(I didn't create this monster, but I need to maintain it which is turning into a real pain ... thanks all for the help.)

Answer (score 2):

If it's just showing an underlying list you're looking for, CSS will be enough. There are many tutorials on how to achieve this, such as: http://lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu/

Comment: It is a list, but the whole thing is created by a repeater ... so the list is read from an XML file. I know in accordions you can set the default to expanded and collapse them on page load, if JS is working.

Only option I see is to have the mouse over selection contain a click event to go to a separate page with the list of menu selections shown ...

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS :hover pseudo classes to mimic it (a limited mimic)

A good place to start

http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/

Comment: true, this is only for IE6 though right? That link has some excellent alternatives.